# Checking toggle state?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head> 
        <title></title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#widget_list").hide();

                $("#click_me").click(function() {
                    $(this).parents( "#clipboard" ).find( "#widget_list" ).toggle();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
       <div id="clipboard">

           <div href="#" id="click_me" style="border:solid 1px black;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;">
                \/
           </div>

           <div id="widget_list" style="border:solid 1px black;text-align:center;">
                some stuff here
           </div>

       </div>

       some other stuff here

    </body> 
</html>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QFTsb/).

Instead of hard coding the text `some stuff here` into `#widget_list`.  How do I add that text to `#widget_list`, when it's toggle state is visible and how do I remove that text from `#widget_list` when it's toggle state is hidden?

Comment: why do you need the text removed when the it is hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/QFTsb/1/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/QFTsb/3/

Using `.is(":visible")` : http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

You can see you will get alert in the demo when it will be visible or now in toggle

This will help

**code**

```
$("#widget_list").hide();

$("#click_me").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("#clipboard").find("#widget_list").toggle(function() { alert($(this).is(':visible'));});
});​
```

Comment: This seems to have enabled animation for some reason.  How do I get rid of that?

Comment: Hiya @oshirowanen hmm animation? `:)` either you can use `.stop` or if you flick me full code in jsfiddle I can make a full working demo for you, cheers

Comment: The original post is all the code I have.  Even in the original jsfiddle examaple, if I use the original example, the toggle is instant, as in it appears and disappears.  However, as soon as I add a function within toggle, it ends up doing a smooth easing type animation.

Comment: For example: no animation here: http://jsfiddle.net/QFTsb/, and animation is enabled here: http://jsfiddle.net/QFTsb/5/...

Comment: Nevermind, if I add a `0` in the toggle, animation disappears, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/QFTsb/10/.

Comment: @oshirowanen lol `:)` you are fast brother :) Glad it helped, have a nice one! +1 to you as well

Answer (score 0):

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/QFTsb/2/)

Just populate some stuff here while you are hiding the Div

```
$("#widget_list").hide(function(){ $(this).html('some stuff here')});

$("#click_me").click(function() {
    $(this).parents( "#clipboard" ).find( "#widget_list" ).toggle();
});​
```